# OBJs not importing to Blender 2.8, is there a workaround?

Tags: import, error

I've very quickly sculpted a few items for a scene I'd like to do a base render for in Blender - and I was hoping to take advantage of Eevee.

However, when I try to import the OBJs, I get the following error:
[image]

When I import into Blender 2.78, it's fine. Is there something simple I can correct here?
Exporting an OBJ of these models after importing to 2.78 will not open in 2.8.

Small OBJ available here as an example.
[Mushroom OBJ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxtsCPRtOPHVqdjclE2G2_xxw9rnLfip/view?usp=sharing)

Thoughts and tips appreciated, as not having to pause for renders would help my art workflow. Thanks <3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a development version of Blender.

Comment: If posting about a development version of Blender is not considered "on topic" - this should be listed in the scope on this page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

That page indicates that all discussion of Blender - without mentioning version - is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Import it in 2.79, save it as a blend and open it in 2.8

Comment: This would be a good comment, this is not a good answer as is